# C# WPF Button on Hover is not filling background fully

Tags: c#, wpf

**Details:**

This is the output of my `Login` Button when hovered:

[image]

**Goal:**

I am aiming to fill the tiny amount of white color with blue, within the button when hovered.

**Code:**

Here is my style code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="login_Btn">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#004263"/>
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica"/>
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>


<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="20"
                                                              BorderThickness="2"
                                                              BorderBrush="#004263">

                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#004263"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

**Question:**

How can I fill the white corners on Hover on the edges of the button?

And

Why is it doing this?

Comment: The suggestion: use common brushes like themes. It will make you safe if you'll decide to change color theme for the entire App. Add to `App.xaml`/`<Application.Resources>` this `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBlueColorKey" Color="#004263" />` and then use like this in any View `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBlueColorKey}"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply curves render issue but I don't think that's a problem.

I came up with a following workaround:

```xaml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="0"/>
        <Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#004263">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```